# Is it possible to pass a reference to a variadic template function?

Tags: c++, c++11, pass-by-reference, variadic-templates

Suppose, I have a base class using CRTP and providing a variadic template static member function

```
template<typename derived_task>
struct task_impl : library::task
{
   /* some useful functionality implemented using CRTP */
   /// static method for spawning a task.
   template<typename... Args>
   static void spawn(Args... args)
   { library::spawn(new task(args...)); }
 };
```

and the derived class

```
struct my_task : task_impl<my_task>
{
  /* implementation using functionality of task_impl<> */
  my_task(container&c, int i);
};
```

and then want to use the variadic template member via

```
container c( /* args for ctor */ );
my_task::spawn(c,0);
```

What happens here is that `spawn()` creates a copy of container rather than passing the original container by reference. Is there any way to enforce a reference?

Comment: `std::ref` should work for this, no?

Comment: it does. thanks. PS. will accept 1-line answer. PPS. in 10 min (not allowed earlier :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options, either wrap the argument with a `reference_wrapper` so the function call copies the `reference_wrapper` not the object it referes to, or make your variadic function use perfect forwarding so that it can pass arguments by reference:

```
template<typename... Args>
 static void spawn(Args&&... args)
 { library::spawn(new task(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); }
```

Comment: Perfect forwarding is, of course, much better than using `std::ref` for an object that is already a reference. In fact, `std::thread` uses that, too. I'm still learning all those techniques used with variadic templates.

Comment: Thanks to your comment I got it to work by taking the varargs as rvalues (or as references): `void spawn(Args...)` ==> `void spawn(Args&&...)`. 

Why should we also use perfect forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::ref` to wrap the parameters.

This actually occurs rather frequently, for example when creating `std::thread`s with functions that take reference parameters, or when using `std::bind`.

Comment: I would not really call it a problem, it just seems that many people forget that for things like `std::bind` and many others, the default is to store things by value.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Point taken, edited so that I no longer call it a problem.

Comment: After having seen Jonathan's answer, I checked on `std::thread` and found that it uses perfect forwarding via `std::forward<>`. So, what's the issue?

Comment: @Walter: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread <- see the description of constructor (3) - it copies the elements you pass in.

Comment: @us2012 `template<typename _Callable, typename... _Args>
      explicit 
      thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
      {
        _M_start_thread(_M_make_routine(std::__bind_simple(
                std::forward<_Callable>(__f),
                std::forward<_Args>(__args)...)));
      }` from gcc 4.8.0. Yes it copies the arguments *perfectly*, rather than making a copy of an object instead of the reference given.

Comment: @Walter, and what does `__bind_simple` do? It uses `std::decay` and copies the arguments by value. Perfect forwarding is used to avoid unnecessary copies _before_ the required by-value copies are done, but those copies are required by the standard.